# The service "fos_user.group_manager" has a dependency on a non-existent service "fos_user.entity_manager"

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I am using symfony 2.8 i want to configure sonata user bundle and fosUserbundle

beolw is my image link:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ4qZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in config.yml

```
fos_user:
    service:
        user_manager: fos_user.user_manager.default
```

You can check this official config reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/configuration_reference.html